# Conveying the idea of "can’t hold a candle to"

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

> If you say that one person or thing can't hold a candle to another, you meant that the first person or thing is not nearly as good as the second.
> E.g.

- There is not one rock star today who could hold a candle to any of those composers.
- Not even the best seats in the grandstand would hold a candle to the view of the action from here.

See for instance [here](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cant-hold-a-candle-to) and for more details [here](https://grammarist.com/idiom/cant-hold-a-candle-to/)

How can one colloquially convey a similar idea in French?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are  two colloquial expressions used often enough for this English idiom; they have variants.

- ne pas arriver à la cheville de
- ne pas arriver au genou de (*not used as often as the preceding*)
- ne pas venir/monter à la ceinture/cheville
- ne pas être digne de dénouer le cordon de ses souliers

La première expression (cheville) est aussi employée pour les choses (comparativement rare)

*exemples tirés de la littérature*

- Ce Dr Slater me semble un bon médecin, mais il n'arrive pas à la cheville du Dr Seymour. J'espère qu'il reviendra bientôt.
- Je suis sûre que Granny a ses raisons, répondit-elle. En plus, Connie fait beaucoup d'efforts. Et pour ce qui est des desserts, je ne lui arrive pas à la cheville.
- Comment pourrais-je être son tuteur alors que je ne lui arrive pas à la cheville ?
- Des filles comme elle, on a toujours l'impression qu'on ne leur arrive pas à la cheville.
- Puisque je ne t'arrive pas à la cheville en matière de décoration, il serait normal que tu sois la seule de nous deux à être rémunérée.
- Bien sûr, il n'arrive pas à la cheville de ces merveilles, dit-il en tapotant le couvercle de la boîte, mais c'est la recette de ma femme.

Comment: Merci. Two or four? Can you provide any examples of usage?

Comment: Cheville, genou, ceinture, tout cela est un peu la même chose, donc il n'y a qu'une expression vu selon ce point de vue. Je vais voir si je trouve des cas réels.